# How do I upload photos from my phone?

Tags: galaxy-nexus

Have pictures in my Galaxy s7 that I would like to upload into my PC with Ubuntu operating system --- is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You have to select the File Transfer mode from a list of modes that are available when you connect your phone to the PC.

Then, a folder will appear which will give access to your phone's storage.

Then, you can go to "DCIM" or "Images" or whatever the name of the folder on your device is, and access the images.